# Huffman code generator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, compression

This is problem 50 in https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/46_to_50. The website has more elegant Haskell solutions, but I wanted to get feedback on how the code I wrote on my own below could be improved.

```
import Data.List

data Tree a = Leaf a Int | Internal (Tree a) (Tree a) Int

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Tree a) where
 (Leaf a ac)         == (Leaf b bc)  = (a == b) && (ac == bc)
 (Internal a1 a2 ac) == (Internal b1 b2 bc) = (a1 == b1) && (a2 == b2) && (ac == bc)
 _   == _  = False

instance (Eq a) => Ord (Tree a) where
 a <= b = (freq a) <= (freq b)

freq :: Tree a -> Int
freq (Leaf _ c) = c
freq (Internal _ _ c) = c

leafMap :: [(a, Int)] -> [Tree a]
leafMap list = map (\(a, count) -> Leaf a count) list 

extractMinFreq :: (Eq a) => [Tree a] -> (Tree a, [Tree a])
extractMinFreq list = (mf , delete mf list)
                      where mf = minimum list

collapseLowest :: (Eq a) => [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
collapseLowest list = (collapsePair s1 s2):xs
                        where
                        (s1,y) = extractMinFreq list
                        (s2, xs) = extractMinFreq y

treeBuilder :: (Eq a) => [Tree a] -> Tree a
treeBuilder list = case len of
                        0 -> error "Empty"
                        1 -> list !! 0
                        _ -> treeBuilder $ collapseLowest list
                    where len = length list

collapsePair :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
collapsePair x y = Internal x y $ (freq x) + (freq y)

prefixBuilder :: Tree Char -> String -> [(Char, String)]
prefixBuilder (Leaf a _) prefix = [(a, prefix)]
prefixBuilder (Internal a b _) prefix = (prefixBuilder a $ prefix ++ "0") ++
                                        (prefixBuilder b $ prefix ++ "1")

huffman :: [(Char, Int)] -> [(Char, String)]
huffman list = prefixBuilder (treeBuilder $ leafMap list) ""

main = print $ huffman [('a',45),('b',13),('c',12),('d',16),('e',9),('f',5)]
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you added a paragraph of text in which you explain the purpose of the code and the issues you encountered while writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Specify imports

Do you know the names of all functions in `Data.List`? Me neither. Specify what you import like

```
import Data.List (delete)
```

In my final version, this becomes

```
import Data.List (minimumBy,partition)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
```

## `Ord` vs `Eq`

Your `Ord` and `Eq` instances do not agree! For `Ord`, only the frequency matters, for `Eq`, both frequency and payload have to be equal. This leads to oddities like this:

```
> let i c x = Internal (Leaf c 0) (Leaf ' ' 0) x -- helper
> i 'a' 1 >= i 'b' 1
False
> i 'b' 1 >= i 'b' 1
True
```

To solve the issue, I'd get rid of the `Ord` instance by

```
where mf = minimumBy (comparing freq) list
```

### Use deriving

You implement a custom `Eq` instance for `Tree`, where `deriving Eq` would suffice. It takes a second to figure out what `deriving Eq` does, to read yours takes longer and does nothing different.

### use pattern matches

`length` and indexing with `!! 0` look like a direct translation from imperative programming. Use pattern matching instead:

```
treeBuilder []   = error "Empty"
treeBuilder [x]  = x
treeBuilder list = treeBuilder $ collapseLowest list
```

The use of length causes an unnecessary traversal of the list and can cause performance issues: In the worst case you lose [list fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578063/what-is-haskells-stream-fusion).

### Getting rid of Eq constraint

Just as `minimumBy` allowed to get rid of the `Ord` instance, `deleteBy` allows to get rid of the `Eq` constraint.

```
extractMinFreq list = (mf , deleteBy ((==) `on` freq) mf list)
```

Now you can compress uncomparable things like functions or IO actions after `Char` has been replaced by `a`.

### Eta reduction

`leafMap` allows eta reduction, the lambda can be written with `uncurry`. (The latter is of dubious value)

```
 leafMap = map (uncurry Leaf)
```

## Github

You can see all steps at https://github.com/Frank-Siebert/codereview86061

Comment: Could you please tell me where you learned about eta reduction and uncurry?